# HTML5 video plays when scrolling with javascript lagging issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, scroll

I am currently designing a site but having trouble getting my video scroll effect to work properly. I got the Java script code using http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GxDJ.

```
/**
 * Animate stuff on scroll
 */
scrollHandler: function() {

    scroll += (target - scroll) * 0.1;

  console.log(scroll);

    if(delta < 0) {
        $video[0].currentTime += (1 / frameRate);
    }
    else {
        $video[0].currentTime -= (1 / frameRate);
    }

    // stop ticking
    isTicking = false;
}
```

The code works fine when using the google video linked in the codepen, but when i use my own video from my site folder it's really laggy and does not look good at all! My guess is it might be something to do with frame rate? I am really not sure though. My current video is 29.9fps and have tried adjusting it in premiere pro but its still really laggy. My second guess is that it might be something to do with the scroll because when i scroll down the page very slowly it kind of works but still lags in some parts. I really hope someone can help with this as i have hit a brick wall! i'm currently hosting my un-finished site [here](http://demihopkin.com) just so you can see what i mean about the lag. Is there anyone that know why its lagging so bad? I'm really stuck and any help is greatly appreciated!

thanks,

Louis =)

Comment: looks to me like your video is hard to play. even jumping around using the seekbar takes a bit of time to update the video display. maybe mp4 would allow quicker seeks than webm.

Comment: Your codepen link is currently not working.

Comment: Frame rate can't be your issue.  Sane settings (29.97, etc) can not impact performance.

Comment: Can you run MediaInfo (http://mediaarea.net/us/MediaInfo/Download) on the offending file and let us know what its properties are?  Video codec, bitrate, file size, and duration are going to be most relevant data to this question.

Comment: Also, I'd be curious to know how you produced this video.  It sounds like it might be an MP4 which has not been massaged (had its MOOV atom moved to the beginning of the file) for streaming.  Can you share your ffmpeg command line?

Comment: Sorry the code pen is http://codepen.io/souporserious/pen/sheIE

Comment: also i took a screen shot of the media info http://i.imgur.com/TEhc02w.png 

Im really sorry but im not sure what you mean by ffmpeg command line? I'l look it up now and get back to you. The video is one i got online its a free stock video.

Comment: Im going to try lowering the kps!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i lowered the Kbps and matched it to the video used on the code-pen and now it works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help! :D

Louis